# How to make sure "cellTable.getColumnSortList().push" sort column Descending?

Tags: gwt

I want `myCellTable` to sort `qtyColumn`  descending. That is the ones with highest qty will be on top.

```
myCellTable.getColumnSortList().push(qtyColumn);
myCellTable.getColumnSortList().push(qtyColumn);
//someone said we have to do the push twice. I did but it still sort Asc. 
So I think the above code doesn't seem elegant
```

I just need 1 simple code that guarantee that the table will show data with qty column sorted desc.

So, How to show table with qty column sorted desc?

**Note:** I found this `public ColumnSortList.ColumnSortInfo(Column<?,?> column, boolean ascending)` but don't know how to use it?

Tried many way but it didn't work.

```
myCellTable.getColumnSortList().push(new ColumnSortInfo(qtyColumn, false)); // not working

 //this is also not working
 ColumnSortInfo sortInfo = myCellTable.getColumnSortList().push(qtyColumn);
 if (sortInfo.isAscending()) {
        myCellTable.getColumnSortList().push(qtyColumn);

 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this seems to work, not sure if it has any problem:

```
table.getColumnSortList().clear();
table.getColumnSortList().push(column);
table.getColumnSortList().push(column);                 
ColumnSortEvent.fire(table, table.getColumnSortList());
```

Comment: Yes, it's working but i need to "push 2 times", updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

**Workaround :** If nothing is working then simply pass a already sorted `List` to the `CellTable` or `ListDataProvider` as per your initial sorting.

use `Collections.sort()`

Its working perfectly for me.

Sample code : (sort by name descending)

```
    Collections.sort(contactList,new Comparator<Contact>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(Contact o1, Contact o2) {
            return o2.name.compareTo(o1.name);
        }
    });

    // Create a data provider.
    ListDataProvider<Contact> dataProvider = new ListDataProvider<Contact>(contactList);

    // Connect the table to the data provider.
    dataProvider.addDataDisplay(table);
```

---

Find a sample code below for sorting on header column's click.

- [ColumnSorting with ListDataProvider](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCellTable.html#columnSorting)

Comment: then u can't ultilize the Push method, besides I don't wanna touch dataProvider cos it can mess up the current order of dataProvider.getList();. This current order is using to control the color of each cell. They invented ColumnSortInfo, so it must be used for doing that simple thing. It's just that we don't know how to use ColumnSortInfo

Comment: i seems to found a solution

Answer (score 0):

Try calling

```
setVisibleRangeAndClearData(Range range, boolean forceRangeChangeEvent)
```

on cell table with second parameter true to force RangeChangeEvent right after push call.